# is there a way to exclude some words from being translated when using google cloud API on javascript?

Tags: javascript, exception

is there a way to exclude some words from being translated when using google cloud API?

As an example lets say we are trying to translate to spanish the following sentence:

On my "playbook" the dogs where funny.

In which everything gets translated with the exception of "Playbook".

Extra notes: **only javascript can be used here**
-in the example i tried to add the words "playbook" and ricky to not be translated.
-i dont have the choice to add an exeption glossary

Hope you guys can help, been trying to find a proper solution to exclude some specific words.

```
 // Check if the text contains the words "playbooks" or "ricky"
    if (text.indexOf("playbooks") === -1 && text.indexOf("ricky") === -1) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("POST", "https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2");
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhr.onload = function() {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
          var translatedText = response.data.translations[0].translatedText;
          
          // Replace all occurrences of quotation marks
          translatedText = translatedText.replace(/"/g, '"');
          
          // Replace the ampersand character with "y"
          translatedText = translatedText.replace(/&/g, "y");

          // Replace the word "playbooks" (with word boundary)
          translatedText = translatedText.replace(/\bplaybooks\b/gi, 'playbooks');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap desired texts with a `span` with translate set to no. as the follwoing

```
<span translate="no">{desired_word}</span>
```

A function to replace all occurrences of text you don't want to translate with no span tags.

```
const preventTranslate = (text, word) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`${word}`, 'gi');
    return text.replace(regex, `<span translate="no">${word}</span>`);
}
```

[Reference](https://groups.google.com/g/google-translate-api/c/CYAZrZ3CMuE)

Comment: thanks but im only able to use javascript on this case so span tag wont work.

Comment: You definitely can use javascript to enclose the particular text in the string with -- literally -- `<span translate = "no">` (your nontranslatable text) `</span>`, and submit that string to the google api. So for your example string send `On my <span translate = "no">"playbook"</span> the dogs where funny.`

Comment: hey Paul, thanks for your answer, i get your point but wouldnt that mean i would need to write a function first to search for the specific terms and then another one to to add the <span>, again this is for translated text so i dont have the option to manually add the original text  and tag the term i dont want to be translated , this is for an elearning platform so theres people writing courses over there, addind additional text daily and using that tearm on diferent paragraphs, is there a better or simpler way to do it?

Comment: @Faint as far as I know, this is the workaround I know. However, I don't see a problem if there are texts are changing, implement a preprocess function that takes the text as argument and do all your desired information before submitting the text to the API. 
In your case, you would just need a simple function .e.g. `const passTranslation = (text, word) => {
 const regex = new RegExp(`${word}`, 'gi');
 return text.replace(regex, `<span translate="no">${word}</span>`);
} `, I added the function in the answer in case it's not clear here.

Comment: i aprreciate it, gonna try it with that and see how it performs